# SELECT entire row based on 2 unique criterias in DB2

Tags: sql, hibernate, db2

I'm reached a limit in my SQL know-how and I'm hoping I can get some help.

I'm working with db2 and Hibernate; I'd like to fetch a row into a domain object based on unique combinations in two columns.

I'm relatively familiar with DISTINCT and GROUP BY clauses but they are not having the desired effect.

Very ineffective SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM table1 a, (SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2 FROM table1) b
WHERE a.field1 = b.field1
AND a.field2 = b.field2
```

Essentially I need a:
SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2 FROM table1 (but I need the whole row returned, not just the field subset.

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out *which* row to return.  The following uses `row_number()` and will return an arbitrary matching row in DB2:

```
select t.*
from (select t.* , row_number() over (partition by field1, field2 order by rand()) as seqnum
      from table1 t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

I am not sure how this translates to hibernate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response; I'll test it out and let you know.

Comment: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-514

Comment: You can read about that error here (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fn514.htm).  It has nothing to do with the SQL statement, which has no cursor component.